# i want to add an if statement that will check if a student ID has a PaymentID currently a newbie in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
 <td>
        @if /*(studentID has a paymentID then do then code below or print "no membership")*/(item.StudentID.Equals(item.Payments.OrderByDescending(p=>p.paymentID)))
        {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payments.OrderByDescending(p => p.paymentID).First().Expires);
        }
        else { 
        @Html.DisplayName("No Memebrship");
        }
    </td>
```

I want to add this statement in my student view which will check if student has a paymentID and if he does it will print the latest one but if he doesnt have a payment made it prints no membership

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag is for questions relating to the Visual Studio application.

Comment: When you say "has a payment ID", will there be records in `item.Payments` without IDs? What is the data type of `paymentID`?

Comment: there wont be any records in item.Payments without any student.IDs, the data type of paymentID is int

Comment: I guess you just want `if (item.Payments.Any())`?

Comment: Thank you please can you answer with that so i can credit you pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you just have to check if there are any payment records. You can use LINQ's Any() for this:

```
@if (item.Payments.Any())
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Payments.OrderByDescending(p => p.paymentID).First().Expires);
}
else { 
    @Html.DisplayName("No Memebrship");
}
```

If there's a chance that `item.Payments` can be null, you could write it like this instead:

```
@if (item.Payments != null && item.Payments.Any())
```

**Edit:** To only include expired payments, try this:

```
@if (item.Payments != null && item.Payments.Any(p => p.Expires < DateTime.Now))
```

Comment: && item.Payments.Any(o=>o.Expires)<DateTime.Now) i tried adding this to your if statement to take into consideration if the member is expired or not, am i doing this correctly?

Comment: The people with a valid expiry date are coming up as "no membership or expired" after i added that code :(

Comment: Is your condition the right way around? At the moment it requires that Expires be less than DateTime.Now (i.e. Expires must be in the past). Perhaps you meant `p.Expires > DateTime.Now`